# Cómo puedo utilizar h5ai en subdirectorios de apache

Tags: apache2, php7

Estoy tratando de utilizar el h5ai como reemplazo del index de apache pero no lo quiero en mi directorio root, puesto q tengo otros sitios en mi server q no funcionarian y por eso lo quiero poner en un subdirectorio para esto instalé debian 9 + apache2 + php7. Luego instalé h5ai en un subdirectorio con todas sus dependencias las cuales verifiqué y me quedó todo ok. En el archivo /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf agregué lo siguiente al final del archivo:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/prueba/
    ServerName prueba.redvecinos.ls.cu
    ServerAlias www.prueba.redvecinos.ls.cu
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/html/prueba/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        php_admin_value engine Off
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php /_h5ai/public/index.php
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

creando la carpeta  /var/www/html/prueba/ y poniendo en su interior el h5ai pero al tratar de acceder desde el navegador a la url http://prueba.redvecinos.ls.cu/ me muestra lo siguiente:

```
<?php

define('H5AI_VERSION', '0.29.0');

define('MIN_PHP_VERSION', '5.5.0');

if (!function_exists('version_compare') || version_compare(PHP_VERSION, MIN_PHP_VERSION, '<')) {
    header('Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8');
    exit('[ERR] h5ai requires PHP ' . MIN_PHP_VERSION . ' or later, but found PHP ' . PHP_VERSION);
}

if (substr(H5AI_VERSION, 0, 1) === '{') {
    header('Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8');
    exit('[ERR] h5ai sources must be preprocessed to work correctly');
}

require_once __DIR__ . '/../private/php/class-bootstrap.php';
Bootstrap::run();
```

No se porque me esta dando este error.
Agradecimientos por adelantado.

Answer (score 0):

bueno creo que lo tuyo tiene que ver con la version de php que usas, actualizala .... no soy experta en esto ... ahora veras que te pido ayuda, pues al menos a ti te sale un error a mi ni eso ...te explico:

debian 9, apache 2.4.25, php 7.0.27 sitio publicado en /www/html/hospital.sg.cu/, dentro un archivo index.htlm y una carpeta nombrada webftp esta es la que quiero indexar con h5ai ... coloque la carpeta h5ai dentro de la carpeta webftp ... pero mi duda es al configurar el .conf en /etc/apache2/sites-available para que funcione ... ahhhh la comprobacion en el navegador de /_h5ai/public/index.php me funciona ...  cualquier ayuda me viene bien. saludos.

Comment: Hola, bienvenida a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu respuesta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

En esta pagina esta todo muy bien explicado, es el sitio oficial de h5ai
https://larsjung.de/h5ai/
Ahora yo te explico en español:
primero debes descargar el fichero de h5ai 
https://release.larsjung.de/h5ai/h5ai-0.29.0.zip

Luego los descomprimes en la carpeta principal del root, puede ser htdocs o www, o como en ubuntu /var/www/html/.

Despues que tienes la carpeta _h5ai en tu directorio root, creas un archivo .htacces y escribes esto:

```
DirectoryIndex  index.html  index.php  /_h5ai/public/index.php
```

Sino funciona escribe la linea anterior al final del fichero httpd.conf o apache2.conf según sea tu caso y reinicia el servicio de apache.

Ahora h5ai cambiara el formato index de todas las capetas que no contengan un archivo index.html o index.php

Espero que te sirva. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Respondo una pregunta antigua porque esto es un problema habitual con una solución sencilla.

Cuando el servidor devuelve el contenido de un script PHP en lugar de ejecutarlo, lo más habitual es que el php esté deshabilitado o que no esté reconociendo el tipo de fichero.

Para el caso concreto de la pregunta, solo debería eliminar o comentar la siguiente línea de la configuración:

```
   php_admin_value engine Off
```

Con esa línea se está desactivando PHP, por lo que el servidor no sabe como interpretar el fichero y lo interpreta como un fichero de texto, mostrando el contenido del mismo.